# sending email from google fails on production server but works ok from localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the code in controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true)]
        public ActionResult Contact(ContactForm model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json("error");

            }
            else
            {

                WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
                WebMail.UserName = //email here
                WebMail.Password = //password here
                WebMail.EnableSsl = true;

                string message = model.Name + " " + model.Telephone + " " + model.Email + " " + model.Address + " " + model.City + " " + model.ZipCode;

                try
                {
                    WebMail.Send("example@example.com", "philaslim.com/info email", message, model.Email);
                    return Json("thanks");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(ex.Message.ToString());
                }

            }
```

As I said it fails only on production server. The returned exception message is "Failure sending mail.". Any ideas?

EDIT: InnerException:

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.53.108:25 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Comment: Is there anything in the InnerException?

Comment: Does your production server require a proxy to access the internet?

Comment: Sending emails from Google is always a pain. I suggest going with a paid service like SendGrid or Amazon SES. They are cheap.

Comment: @hawkke I am just using Godaddy. It's only one landing page for a client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your outgoing SMTP ports(25,587) are probably closed on your server, check your firewall settings.

Comment: I am using godaddy. I'll have to call them I guess.

Comment: You saved my life - This is due in few hours! Thanks a lot!